# Supporter of political corruption

Tags: nouns, adjectives

What will be the word for people who support corruption or keep their eyes, ears and mouths shut upon witnessing political corruption?

Comment: What is, not what will be. Because if it isn't now, it cannot be in the future.....you said it: supporters of political corruption.

Comment: You are right. Thank you.

What is a word for people who support corruption; or keep their eyes, ears and mouths shut upon witnessing political corruption?

Comment: Can you supply a sentence with a blank where the word you want would fit? As it stands, a wide range of words might answer your question. For example, "Many people in Germany were actively and passively _________ in Hitler's crimes." For this sentence, 'complicit' would fit, but I've no certainty that's the kind of word, or the meaning, you're looking for.

Comment: I would say "Many in Germany connived at Hitler's crimes."

Answer (score 1):

"Collaborator" is one that was used in relation to those who worked with the Nazis. "Quisling" is another term, derived from Vidkum Quisling, a Norwegian politician who ran the pro-Nazi puppet government after they invaded. Either of these could be used more generally in your context.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a ***colluder***.

TFD:

> **[collude](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/colluder)**
>   *intr.v.*
>
> To act together, often in secret, to achieve an illegal or improper
>   purpose:
>
> "The managers and the union leaders regularly colluded to rob the
>   plantations at the expense of the workers"
>
> **colluder** *n*.